# Static build in Qt on Windows Vista

Tags: c++, qt, static, build, windows-vista

I am currently running Windows Vista Home Premium, and I have developed an application with my friend using Qt Creator. We are now trying to deploy our application as just one executable, so we are trying to do a static build. We have added CONFIG += static in our .pro file.

We are using this documentation to help us:

```
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/deployment-windows.html
```

When I try to build QT, I use this command:

```
configure -static -platform win32-msvc
```

Then I get this error:

```
Creating qmake...
execute: File or path is not found (nmake)
execute: File or path is not found (nmake)
Cleaning qmake failed, return code -1
```

I think I have to add nmake to my PATH, but I can't find it on my computer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You will find a batch file under the bin directory of your visual studio install called "vcvars32.bat".  Run that from the command line before you try building QT.  That should solve your problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We were actually able to compile it, but now the executable is around 70 MB unfortunately.

Comment: built in release or debug mode?

Answer (score 1):

Open **Visual Studo 20xx Command Prompt** and compile Qt inside it!

For instance, on VS2008 I also need to set `QMAKESPEC` before trying to configure Qt:

```
set QMAKESPEC=<QT_DIR>\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008
```