# Qt (MSVC2010) - dependencies only found on machine where Qt is installed

Tags: c++, qt

For full Story: someone has the exact same problem here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/50118/windows-qt-deployment-not-working-vs2010-qt-5-4-0

**Short story and Question:**

Is there anything Qt-Installer sets during the installation process of the SDK? My Application works only on machines where Qt is installed (C:/Program Files/Qt). I checked the env variables but there is nothing Qt related.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there are no these paths in your env. vars. But you can find these paths in your .exe and .dll files (in result of compilation for Windows). Usual Qt program knows full path to all Qt's .dll files on developer's computer.

Comment: @Ilya you wrong. Program doesn't know. This path is stored in `Qt5Core.dll`. So only if `Qt5Core.dll` is resolved - then application knows a path on a developer machine. Otherwise - not.

Comment: Is there a way of defining this path in qt5core.dll? And how can qt5core.dll know the path when its prebuild?

Comment: and will this explain, why an exe is not executed even though when all dll files are copied to the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything Qt-Installer sets during the installation process of
>   the SDK?

Yes. During installation original path to Qt is hardcoded to QtXXX.dll's. So, in some cases, it is necessary to use `qt.conf` file.

Some links, to read more:

[Reason of your problem](http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=536)

[Official documentation for `qt.conf`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html)

[Deployment of Qt applications](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html)

Comment: actually that solved my problem indirectly, knowing that the pathes are hardcoded! thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two ways: the easy one, and the right one. The easy one is to copy all the dlls the application needs (i.e. all that appear in the error messages when you try to launch the app) to the same folder where your app's executable is. That should work, but that's ugly.

The right way is to make a static build of Qt, and use it to compile your application. The static application build this way will be portable as is - you will be able to launch it on any machine. The process of bilding a static version of Qt is described in the documentation [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows) or [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW) (basically it just requires compiling Qt with `-static` flag), and in some other [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940926/making-static-buildstandalone-application-with-qt)

Comment: However, a static build does not comply the LGPL licence, if OP is using it (and not the commercial one).

Comment: @Melebius, I think it can also be used if the OP's application is open-source? Anyway, if he doesn't want it, he can always copy the dlls

Comment: I think it has to be _GPL_ and not just _open-source_ which is a broader term.

Comment: i've copied the dlls in **C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\plugins** but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Qt (on Windows) installs its DLLs and adds the folder containing them to the `PATH` variable. You can provide the DLL binaries along with your application on the base of [LGPL](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/lgpl.html).

Comment: i checked the PATH variable, there is no reference to Qt

Comment: Aren’t the DLL installed in an already-present folder like `Windows\System32`? Then the Qt installer wouldn’t need to touch `PATH`. I use Qt 4.8, they may have changed it since that version…